# how to validate cell number

Tags: javascript

i have to validate the cell no and my requirements are :

1.filed must not empty
2. if user enter alphabetic value it pop-up "alphabets are not allowed"
3. field must start with "+" sign
4. if filed value is less than 13 it pop-up "please enter valid phone no"

i am using this code..

```
function validateForm()
{

    var cell = document.reg_form.cellno.value;
            if(cell.length==0) 
            {
                alert("Please enter cell number");
                reg_form.cellno.focus();
                return false;
            }

           if(isNaN(cell)||cell.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
              {
                 alert("Enter numeric value")
                 return false; 
              }


            if (cell.charAt(0)!="+")
              {
                alert("Cell no should start with +");
                return false
              }

                if(cell.length < 13) 
               {
              alert("You have entered wrong number");
              reg_form.cellno.focus();
              return false;
        }
return true;
}
```

some code is not working here
when i enter numeric value.. it shows {"Cell no should start with "+"}
when i put {+} sign it says please enter numeric value
when i enter only single numeric value like {9} it goes forward.. although in this way field has only 2 value "+" and "9".. it should pop-up {"You have entered wrong number"}

please tell me where i made the mistake....

Comment: + is not numeric, therefore, isNaN(cell) will always return true. Also, `if(cell.length > 13)` should be `if(cell.length != 13)`

Comment: if(isNaN(cell)||cell.indexOf(" ")!=-1) returns false.. so that i can enter numeric value to... but i enter only 2 or 3 numbers and it goes forward.. why thid does not return false in `if(cell.length > 13) ` .. as my filed values are less than 13

Comment: @user1090190: Surely a leading + gives a valid number.

Comment: @Bergi you're might, my mistake. :x

Comment: i made mistake.. i want message if cell no is less than 13... mistakenly i enterd `>` sign .. what should i do to validate this

Comment: @maham: So then, is there a problem left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison of the cell length with 13 returns true (and alerts) if the value is longer than 13. I suspect you wanted

```
if(cell.length < 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression that matches only a plus sign and 12 digits:

```
function validateForm(){
    var cell = document.reg_form.cellno;
     return  /^\+\d{12}$/.test(cell.value);
}
```

Comment: Use seperate RegEx, test first for /^\+ to see if it starts with a plus, then /^\+\d{12}$/ to make sure its + and 12 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm()
{
     var cell=document.reg_form.cellno.value;
     var msg="";
     if(cell.length==0) 
     {
         msg="Please enter cell number";
         alert(msg);
         reg_form.cellno.focus();
         return false;
     }

     if(isNaN(cell)) msg+="\nEnter numeric value";
     if (cell.charAt(0)!="+") msg+="\nCell no should start with +";
     if(cell.length != 13) msg+="\nCell number must be within 13 characters";
     if(msg) 
     {
         alert((msg));
         reg_form.cellno.focus();
         return false;
     }
     return true;  
}
```

[**An example is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7tHRt/1/).